# How to cache the gzip content in nginx?

Tags: nginx

when several clients request the same file, which is responsed by the gzip function in nginx . I hope that other responses could use the cached gzip content . How to config ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a discussion of the same in NGINX forums.
I find that [this suggestion](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,270604,270648#msg-270648) makes the most sense. However, it mostly applies to when you do `proxy` with NGINX and not `fastcgi` cache.

Essentially you will ensure `Accept-Encoding: gzip` is sent to your backend to ensure that you always generate/cache gzipped content, and then use `gunzip` module for clients that don't request gzip encoding.